# Why is Chrome auto-populating my input field?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

I think this is a bit of an odd issue - I'm having a strange error and I'm not sure whether it's coming from wrong code, React, MaterialUI or Chrome.

I have a React app which includes a 'My Account' page which allows users to change their details.  This page has a form which lists the user's details (name, address etc) as a series of `Mui InputBases`.  Initially the form is filled with the current values (if any exist - this info has been read from the database before the screen is rendered); the user can then make changes and save them.

The form basically looks like this (I've taken out labels and error handling, for clarity):

```
<TextField
  value={formState.firstName}
  onChange={(v) => onChangeText('firstName', v)}
/>
<TextField
  value={formState.lastName}
  onChange={(v) => onChangeText('lastName', v)}
/>
<TextField
  value={formState.email}
  onChange={(v) => onChangeText('email', v)}
/>
<TextField
  value={formState.address1}
  onChange={(v) => onChangeText('address1', v)}
/>
<TextField
  value={formState.city}
  onChange={(v) => onChangeText('city', v)}
/>
<TextField
  value={formState.postcode}
  onChange={(v) => onChangeText('postcode', v)}
/>
```

When the form is rendered, the `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` are correctly populated with values which have been initialised (based on info from the database).  The other 3 fields are all initially blank (because they're not completed in the database), but then `postcode` immediately changes and shows my email address.  If I take out the postcode field, `city` gets filled instead.  If I rearrange them, whichever one is at the end of the form gets filled.

By adding logs, I've figured out that onChangeText is being called for the final field after the initial render; it changes the text to the email address.

I assume this is something to do with Chrome auto-completing fields (just as it auto-completes email address and password on the login page), and it has somehow decided that the final field here should be auto-filled with email address too.

Has anyone come across this before?  Is there a way to prevent it?  Or have I got the reason wrong and it's actually an error in my code, or something in Mui or React?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser autocomplete on web form field / input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags)

Comment: Thanks, that link is helpful - looks like it's an autocomplete issue rather than something I've coded badly, so that's good to know!